# Implicitly invoking parent class initializer

Tags: python, constructor, super, python-2.x, method-resolution-order

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        #super(A, self).__init__()
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()


class B(A):
    def __init__(self, b, c):
        print super(B, self)
        print super(self.__class__, self)
        #super(B, self).__init__(1, b, c)
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__(1, b, c)

class C(B):
    def __init__(self, c):
        #super(C, self).__init__(2, c)
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__(2, c)
C(3)
```

In the above code, the commented out `__init__` calls appear to the be the commonly accepted "smart" way to do super class initialization. However in the event that the class hierarchy is likely to change, I have been using the uncommented form, until recently.

It appears that in the call to the super constructor for `B` in the above hierarchy, that `B.__init__` is called again, `self.__class__` is actually `C`, not `B` as I had always assumed.

**Is there some way in Python-2.x that I can maintain proper MRO (with respect to initializing all parent classes in the correct order) when calling super constructors while not naming the current class (the `B` in in `super(B, self).__init__(1, b, c)`)?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: no, there's no way to implicitly invoke the right `__init__` with the right arguments of the right parent class in Python 2.x.

Incidentally, the code as shown here is incorrect: if you use super().`__init__`, then all classes in your hierarchy must have the same signature in their `__init__` methods.  Otherwise your code can stop working if you introduce a new subclass that uses multiple inheritance.

See http://fuhm.net/super-harmful/ for a longer description of the issue (with pictures).

Comment: i was beginning to wonder about the init signatures and multiple inheritance

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps what you are looking for is metaclasses?

```
class metawrap(type):
    def __new__(mcs,name, bases, dict):
        dict['bases'] = bases
        return type.__new__(mcs,name,bases,dict)

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def test(self):
        print "I am class A"

class B(A):
    __metaclass__ = metawrap
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def test(self):
        par = super(self.bases[0],self)
        par.__thisclass__.test(self)
foo = B()
foo.test()
```

Prints "I am class A"

What the metaclass does is overriding the initial creation of the B class (not the object) and makes sure that the builtin dictionary for each B object now contains a bases array where you can find all the baseclasses for B

Comment: I just realized I'm shooting sparrows with cannons (danish proverb), for that I apologize, I will however let this be unless someone decides to delete it.

Comment: i'd prefer not to resort to metaclasses for something that should be trivial, but thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your code has nothing to do with method resolution order. Method resolution comes in the case of multiple inheritance which is not the case of your example. Your code is simply wrong because you assume that `self.__class__` is actually the same class of the one where the method is defined and this is wrong:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         print self.__class__
... 
>>> 
>>> class B(A):
...     def __init__(self):
...         A.__init__(self)
... 
>>> B()
<class '__main__.B'>
<__main__.B object at 0x1bcfed0>
>>> A()
<class '__main__.A'>
<__main__.A object at 0x1bcff90>
>>>
```

so when you should call:

```
super(B, self).__init__(1, b, c)
```

you are indeed calling:

```
# super(self.__class__, self).__init__(1, b, c)
super(C, self).__init__(1, b, c)
```

**EDIT**: trying to better answer the question.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        for cls in self.__class__.mro():
            if cls is not object:
                cls._init(self, a)
    def _init(self, a):
        print 'A._init'
        self.a = a

class B(A):
    def _init(self, a):
        print 'B._init'

class C(A):
    def _init(self, a):
        print 'C._init'

class D(B, C):
    def _init(self, a):
        print 'D._init'


d = D(3)
print d.a
```

prints:

```
D._init
B._init
C._init
A._init
3
```

(A modified version of [template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_Method_Pattern)).

Now parents' methods are really called implicitly, but i have to agree with python zen where explicit is better than implicit because the code is lesser readable and the gain is poor. But beware that all `_init` methods have the same parameters, you cannot completely forget about parents and I don't suggest to do so.

For single inheritance, a better approach is explicitly calling parent's method, without invoking `super`. Doing so you don't have to *name the current class*, but still you must care about who is the parent's class.

Good reads are: [how-does-pythons-super-do-the-right-thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607186/how-does-pythons-super-do-the-right-thing) and the links suggested in that question and in particularity [Python's Super is nifty, but you can't use it](http://fuhm.net/super-harmful/)

If hierarchy is likely to change is symptoms of bad design and has consequences in all the parts who are using that code and should not be encouraged.

**EDIT 2**

Another example comes me in mind, but which uses metaclasses. Urwid library [uses metaclass](http://excess.org/urwid/browser/urwid/util.py#L413) to store an attribute, `__super`, in class so that you need just to access to that attribute.

Ex:

```
>>> class MetaSuper(type):
...     """adding .__super"""
...     def __init__(cls, name, bases, d):
...         super(MetaSuper, cls).__init__(name, bases, d)
...         if hasattr(cls, "_%s__super" % name):
...             raise AttributeError, "Class has same name as one of its super classes"
...         setattr(cls, "_%s__super" % name, super(cls))
... 
>>> class A:
...  __metaclass__ = MetaSuper
...  def __init__(self, a):
...   self.a = a
...   print 'A.__init__'
... 
>>> class B(A):
...  def __init__(self, a):
...   print 'B.__init__'
...   self.__super.__init__(a)
... 
>>> b = B(42)
B.__init__
A.__init__
>>> b.a
42
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, the following isn't commonly done. But it does seem to work.

Methods in a given class definition always mangle double-underscore attributes to include the name of the class they're defined in. So, if you stash a reference to the class in name-mangled form where the instances can see it, you can use that in the call to `super`.

An example stashing the references on the object itself, by implementing `__new__` on the baseclass:

```
def mangle(cls, name):
    if not name.startswith('__'):
        raise ValueError('name must start with double underscore')
    return '_%s%s' % (cls.__name__, name)

class ClassStasher(object):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = object.__new__(cls)
        for c in cls.mro():
            setattr(obj, mangle(c, '__class'), c)
        return obj

class A(ClassStasher):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'init in A', self.__class
        super(self.__class, self).__init__()

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'init in B', self.__class
        super(self.__class, self).__init__()

class C(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'init in C', self.__class
        super(self.__class, self).__init__()

class D(B, C):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'init in D', self.__class
        super(self.__class, self).__init__()


d = D()    
print d
```

And, doing a similar thing, but using a meta-class and stashing the `__class` references on the class objects themselves:

```
class ClassStasherType(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attributes):
        setattr(cls, mangle(cls, '__class'), cls)

class ClassStasher(object):
    __metaclass__ = ClassStasherType

class A_meta(ClassStasher):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'init in A_meta', self.__class
        super(self.__class, self).__init__()

class B_meta(A_meta):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'init in B_meta', self.__class
        super(self.__class, self).__init__()

class C_meta(A_meta):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'init in C_meta', self.__class
        super(self.__class, self).__init__()

class D_meta(B_meta, C_meta):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'init in D_meta', self.__class
        super(self.__class, self).__init__()


d = D_meta()    
print d
```

Running this all together, as one source file:

```
% python /tmp/junk.py
init in D <class '__main__.D'>
init in B <class '__main__.B'>
init in C <class '__main__.C'>
init in A <class '__main__.A'>
<__main__.D object at 0x1004a4a50>
init in D_meta <class '__main__.D_meta'>
init in B_meta <class '__main__.B_meta'>
init in C_meta <class '__main__.C_meta'>
init in A_meta <class '__main__.A_meta'>
<__main__.D_meta object at 0x1004a4bd0>
```