# What does `super()` mean in `__new__`

Tags: python, python-3.x

Note: Part of a flyweight implementation with Python

```py
import weakref

class CarModel:
    _models = weakref.WeakValueDictionary()

    def __new__(cls, model_name, *args, **kwargs):
        model = cls._models.get(model_name)
        if not model:
            model = super().__new__(cls)
            cls._models[model_name] = model    
        return model

    def __init__(self, model_name, air=False):
        if not hasattr(self, "initted"):
          self.model_name = model_name
          self.air = air
          self.initted=True
```

Question 1> what does `super()` mean? Does it mean the parent class of `CarModel`?

Question 2> I also have difficulties to understand the how the function `__new__` works? Specifically, the following line.

```
model = super().__new__(cls)
```

Description for `__new__`:

> The constructor function is called `__new__` as opposed to `__init__`, and
>   accepts exactly one argument, the class that is being constructed (it
>   is called before the object is constructed, so there is no self
>   argument). It also has to return the newly created object.

Comment: @Ben, based on the [document](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types), `__new__()` returns an instance of `cls`. why the code `model = super().__new__(cls)
` in OP can create an instance of `cls`? How does the super class of CarModel know how to create an instance of its subclass?

Comment: That would be a great SO question on its own (if it hasn't already been asked). The short answer is that you're passing it the current class with the `cls` parameter. Ultimately there's no way to actually create a new instance at all without deferring all the way back to `object.__new__`, because Python has no instruction for "allocate an instance". But `object.__new__` knows to create an instance of the class it's passed (which will also be an instance of `object`, because everything is an instance of `object`).

Answer (score 36):

To begin with `super()` in itself is simply shorthand for `super(A, B)`, where `A` is the class wherein the code occurs, and `B` is the first argument to the function in which the code occurs; so in your particular case, `super().__new__(cls)` expands to `super(CarModel, cls).__new__(cls)`.

In turn, `super(T, O)` returns a "super object". To understand what a super object does, you need to understand how attribute references on instances and classes work in Python.

Assuming no `__getattr__` or `__getattribute__` methods are involved, referencing attribute `A` on an object `O` (that is, evaluating `O.A` or `getattr(O, "A")`) proceeds through the following steps:

1. If `"A"` is defined in `O`'s instance dict (`O.__dict__`), then the value on that dict is returned directly, precisely as it is.
2. Otherwise, each of the classes in `O`'s method resolution order are checked in turn, looking for `"A"` in each of their dicts. If found, call the value `D`.
3. If `D`, in turn, does not define a `__get__`, then it is returned as it is. If it does, however, then `D` is referred to as a "descriptor", and its `__get__` method is called with `O` as the first argument, and `type(O)` as the second argument.

An attribute reference on a class works about the same, substituting the class being reference for the instance, with the following differences:

- Step 1 doesn't apply.
- The `__get__` method is called with `None` as the first argument, and the class being referenced as the second.

Python uses descriptors to implement such things as instance methods, class methods, static methods, and properties.

A super object created with `super(T, O)`, then, is a (built-in) object with a `__getattribute__` method which is called on every attribute reference on it, and looks up the attribute in the dicts of the *only classes following T* in `O`'s MRO. The value it then finds, it calls `__get__` on as usual.

The process is a bit complex, so as an example, here's how it would work on your specific case. Since `CarModel` is defined as it is, its MRO is `[CarModel, object]`.

1. `super().__new__(cls)` expands to `super(CarModel, cls).__new__(cls)`, as described above.
2. `super(CarModel, cls)` is evaluated to yield a super object `S`.
3. Python fetches the attribute `"__new__"` on `S` (the equivalent of calling `getattr(S, "__new__")` in Python code).
4. Since `S` was created on the `CarModel` class, it considers the classes following `CarModel` in the MRO of `CarModel`, and finds `"__new__"` in the dict of the `object` class itself. Its value, a static method, has a `__get__` method, which is called with the arguments `None` and `cls`. Since `__new__` is a static method, its `__get__` method simply returns the function as it is, unmodified. Therefore, `super(CarModel, cls).__new__` is precisely the same as `object.__new__`.
5. The function obtained in the last step (that is, `object.__new__`) is called with the `cls` argument, where `cls` is probably `CarModel`, finally a new instance of the `CarModel` class.

I hope that was at all understandable.

(For the sake of completeness, it should be mentioned that the actual `__new__` function on the `object` class is not actually a static method, but a special built-in function that simply has no `__get__` method at all, but since the `__get__` method on static methods just return the function they were defined with, the effect is the same.)

Comment: In `super(class1, class2)`, how does `super` use `class1` and `class2`?

Comment: @Adrian: I don't think I understand your question, because that sounds like what the whole answer is meant to explain. Is there any particular part about it?

Answer (score 5):

`super()` is used to reference the superclass (i.e. the parent class from which you are subclassing).

`__new__` is a method that is invoked to create a new instance of the class, if it is defined.

Comment: In `super(class1, class2)`, how does `super` use `class1` and `class2`?

Answer (score 1):

I believe, you are using Python3, where the super does not need to be provided with the same class name. Super refers to the Base classes of the current class and does the proper [Method Resolution Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607186/how-does-pythons-super-do-the-right-thing) for you to invoke the method from the correct base class. `__new__` is the method which is invoked to create an instance. It is the [first step in the instance creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674304/pythons-use-of-new-and-init).

Comment: In `super(class1, class2)`, how does `super` use `class1` and `class2`?

Answer (score 0):

I think part of this answer is confused about the relationship between `__new__` and `__init__`. I was confused about this myself. Here's how to answer these kind of questions.

> Before we begin it is important to note that defining `__new__` always has an invisible/magic `@classmethod` decorator applied to it.

```
from inspect import signature # find function signature

class JustInit(object):
  def __init__(self, a):
    self.a = a

print("JustInit")
print(signature(JustInit.__new__))
print(signature(JustInit.__init__))
```

> ```
> JustInit
> (*args, **kwargs)
> (self, a, b)
> ```

Well, that's not helpful. Let's inspect those `*args` and `**kwargs` by printing them and passing them through with `super` as suggested by @Dolda2000

```
class PrintNew(object):
  def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    print("new args:", args, "new kwargs:", kwargs)
    return super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

  def __init__(self, a):
    self.a = a

print("PrintNew")
print(signature(PrintNew.__new__))
print(signature(PrintNew.__init__))

pnew = PrintNew(42)
print(pnew.a)
```

Results in:

> ```
> PrintNew
> (cls, *args, **kwargs)
> (self, a)
> new args: (42,) new kwargs: {}
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/home/rett/notes/python/super_new.py", line 21, in <module>
>     pnew = PrintNew(42)
>   File "/home/rett/notes/python/super_new.py", line 12, in __new__
>     return super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
> TypeError: object.__new__() takes exactly one argument (the type to instantiate)
> ```

Wait... I thought the signature of **new** was `*args, **kwargs`... oh, the [`*args` must really be just the `cls`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/__new__-in-python/)?

While this is true, it is extremely important to point out that:

1. `object` only takes the `cls` variable (it doesn't really take `*args/**kwargs`)
2. your implementation of `__new__` can take whatever values are passed to your `__init__` and *do whatever you want with them*.
3. it seems like maybe `__new__` returns a non-instantiated class, which then gets `__init__` called on it.

With these theories, let's try again by replacing `return super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)` with `return super().__new__(cls)`

It now behaves as expected:

> ```
> PrintNew
> (cls, *args, **kwargs)
> (self, a)
> new args: (42,) new kwargs: {}
> 42
> ```

This might give you some ideas on how you can do your implementation.