# Mixin for Django generic views, how can object have a superclass?

Tags: python, django

So the background detail, Post is a model, and I am basically trying to create a blog, the same blog as the one shown in this [video](http://gettingstartedwithdjango.com/en/lessons/microblog-kitchen-sink/).

Here is the code:

```
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView

from models import Post


class PublishedPostsMixin(object):
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(PublishedPostsMixin, self).get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(published=True)


class PostListView(PublishedPostsMixin, ListView):
    # PostListView takes default template name as `post_list.html`,
    # as list was the name it was assigned.
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/post_list.html'                            


class PostDetailView(PublishedPostsMixin, DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/post_detail.html'
```

So, if you can see, `PublishedPostsMixin` is inheriting from object, so how is it that the `super()` is working. If you can understand what is going on, could you please explain step by step, I'm a little confused.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/607186/how-does-pythons-super-do-the-right-thing Can this be helpful?

Comment: The mixin isn't supposed to be used by itself. It will work only when applied to classes which define a `get_queryset` method.

Comment: @AdriánLópez : Thanks, I know that, but how does it work the way it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is in what `super` does. It's a dynamic call: it refers to the next class up in the MRO (method resolution order). Because (as Adrián says in the comments) the mixin is only supposed to be used in conjunction with other classes, there will *always* be something in between `PublishedPostsMixin` and `object` in the MRO.

For more details on `super`, you should read Raymond Hettinger's article [Super considered super](http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) (note that it's written with Python 3 syntax in mind, but the principles are the same).