# Does anybody has a good example of how to use super() to Pass Control to Other Classes?

Tags: python, super

I have just learned that `super()` allows you to call a method in a base class from within the overridden method in a subclass. But can you please explain to me with a good example?

Comment: http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does Python's "super" do the right thing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/607186/how-does-pythons-super-do-the-right-thing)

Comment: I'm afraid the "how does it do it" part is typically irrelevant for beginners trying to understand just the "how can I use it" part; but of course it doesn't hurt to mention it either!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you can just call parent class methods directly by doing `Parent.foo(self, ...)`, but in case of multiple inheritance, `super()` is much more useful;  also, even with single inheritance, `super()` helps you by not forcing you to hardcode the parent class into the child class, so if you change it, calls using `super()` will just continue working.

```
class Base(object):
    def foo(self):
        print 'Base'


class Child1(Base):
    def foo(self):
        super(Child1, self).foo()
        print 'Child1'


class Child2(Base):
    def foo(self):
        super(Child2, self).foo()
        print 'Child2'



class GrandChild(Child1, Child2):
    def foo(self):
        super(Child2, self).foo()
        print 'GrandChild'

Base().foo()
# outputs:
# Base

Child1().foo()
# outputs:
# Base
# Child1

Child2().foo()
# outputs:
# Base
# Child2

GrandChild().foo()
# outputs:
# Base
# Child1
# Child2
# GrandChild
```

You can find out more in the documentation, and by googling "diamond inheritance" or "diamond inheritance python".

Comment: Thanks it gave me good ideas, and could you help me in understanding with __init__() at the inherited classes.

Comment: `__init__` works just like any other method with regards with inheritance—you also have to explicitly call the superclass `__init__` either using `super(...)` or not... also, please accept my answer if it answered your question or at least you found it useful! :)