# Why is an __init__ skipped when doing Base.__init__(self) in multiple inheritance instead of super().__init__()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiple-inheritance, super, diamond-problem

Why *exactly* is

```
A.__init__()
B.__init__()
D.__init__()
```

printed by the following code? In particular:

1. Why is `C.__init__()` **not** printed?
2. Why is `C.__init__()` printed if I put `super().__init__()` instead of `A.__init__(self)`?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(A, self).__init__()
        print("A.__init__()")
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        A.__init__(self)
        print("B.__init__()")
class C(A):
    def __init__(self):
        A.__init__(self)
        print("C.__init__()")
class D(B, C):
    def __init__(self):
        super(D, self).__init__()
        print("D.__init__()")

D()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### tl;dr: because `B.__init__` is what was supposed to call `C.__init__` via `super(B, self).__init__()`, and you bypassed that call.

---

**Why is C.__init__() not printed?**

Because you didn't tell it to.  Multiple inheritance involves cooperation and you've used explicit class references, denying that cooperation.

Had you replaced all of the "super-like" calls with `super().__init__()` (since you've tagged it Python 3) you'd see output like:

```
A.__init__()
C.__init__()
B.__init__()
D.__init__()
```

In fact, you'd see this output if you changed just `B`'s "super-like" call to either:

```
super(B, self).__init__()
super().__init__()
```

So why did A not call C in your case?

It would be redundant to copy the well-outlined answers elsewhere on the site about the MRO.

- [How does Python's super() work with multiple inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance)
- [How does Python's "super" do the right thing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607186/how-does-pythons-super-do-the-right-thing)

**Why is C.__init__() printed if I put super().__init__() instead of A.__init__(self)?**

Because [the no-argument super() goes left to right](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/method-resolution-order.html), so `B` is looked at first, and then inside B you're using an explicit class reference (`A.__init__(self)`).  And in doing so you lose all (most*) context that D *also* had as a superclass `C`.

`super()` is what helps you navigate the MRO, and would have gotten you to `C.__init__()` had you let it.  But in `B` you're just calling a classmethod of `A`.

*As you've noted `C.__init__()` is never called.  However, `C` still shows up in `D.__bases__`:

```
(<class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.C'>)
```

in `D.__mro__`:

```
(<class '__main__.D'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>)
```

and `isinstance(D(), C) is True`.

In short, Python *knows* that `C` is a superclass of `D`, but you gave the `C.__init__` and end-run with your `B.__init__` implementation.

Comment: I can't make sense of this after reading your answer. How and why exactly should the lack of `super` in the **first superclass** affect whether there is a call to the function in the **second superclass**, when the other classes are kept the same? You're just telling me "it involves cooperation" and that I could fix it by calling `super`.. that's obvious in the question. The question is what does that actually mean internally, and how do I make sense of it? Does it mean `super` maintains state between invocations, for example? What state does it hold, and why? How does that get screwed up?

Comment: `super` doesn't maintain state, but can be used to find the next class on the MRO easily.  You don't *need* `super()`, you could have done "what `super()` would have done" by calling `C.__init__` inside of `B`.  If you think that would look weird, that unrelated classes should reference each other that way I agree, and that's why `super()` exists.

Comment: `super()` takes two things, (a) the current class, and (b) the `self` instance -- it uses the MRO of (b) and the position of (a) on it to find the next class in the MRO. In Python3 these things don't need to be explicitly supplied.

Comment: Re: *How and why exactly should the lack of super in the first superclass affect whether there is a call to the function in the second superclass?*  Because ***the thing*** that gets you from B to C (in the case of your `D` instance, at least) ***is super()***.

Comment: Holy cow, `B.__init__` is calling `C.__init__`?!? Wow. Thanks, that makes sense now!!

Comment: @Mehrdad correct :)  (provided `B.__init__` uses `super()` of course)

Comment: Yeah, wow. It never hit me that could be happening, though in hindsight I could've figured it out with some prints if I had just thought of the possibility!