# Do I need to pass attributes from superclass's "__init__" to subclass's "__init__" manually, even if I use "super()"?

Tags: python

In the example below - taken from Python Crash Course book - why do we pass `make`, `model` and `year` to the subclass `__init__` method?

Isn't `super()` supposed to already transfer those parameters to the subclass's `__init__` method automatically?

```
class Car():
    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year

class ElectricCar(Car):
    def __init__(self, make, model, year):  
        super().__init__(make, model, year)
```

Comment: This code does not "pass `make`, `model` and `year` to the subclass `__init__` method"

Comment: If you aren't doing anything else in it, there's no reason to have an `ElectricCar.__init__` at all, as it inherits the one from `Car`.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh This is what I thought as well. I wonder what was the reason for providing such example in this otherwise excellent book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While your wording wasn't quite right (the arguments are actually passed from the *subclass* to the *superclass*), the answer is **yes**, you need to manually pass the arguments in for `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)`.  Otherwise you will encounter a `TypeError` complaining about the missing required positional/keyword arguments.

In your example, it seemed unnecessary [but you trimmed a key line after the `super().__init__()`](https://github.com/crystalDf/Python-Crash-Course-Chapter-09-Classes/blob/master/electric_car.py):

```
class ElectricCar(Car):
    def __init__(self, make, model, year):  
        super().__init__(make, model, year)
        self.battery = Battery()
```

This makes it necessary to redefine the `__init__` in your subclass `ElectricCar`, as `Car` doesn't have the attribute `battery`.

**Note** that for immutable superclass however, you *don't* need to pass in any argument:

```
class Foo(int):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        super().__init__()
```

It would just take your subclass arguments as is at the point of `__new__()`.  In this case, if you *did* manually pass in any argument, to the `super().__init()`, the interpreter would complain that the superclass's `__init__` method doesn't take any argument.  You can quickly see why this seems useless, but [here's a related question on properly inheriting from `str`/`int`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673651/inheritance-from-str-or-int) (if necessary).

Answer (score 2):

> why do we pass make, model and year to the subclass **init** method?

How else would it pass them to it's superclass ?

> Isn't super() supposed to already transfer those parameters to the subclass's **init** method automatically?

No. `Super()` returns a proxy to the next class in the MRO (cf [How does Python's "super" do the right thing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607186/how-does-pythons-super-do-the-right-thing) for more about the `super` object etc). And it's not "transfering" "to the subclass", it's the subclass that uses `super()` to call the parent's implementation.

Note that in this example, the `ElectricCar`'s `__init__` method is totally useless - it only delegates to the parent and do nothing else, so you can just remove it and the parent's `__init__` will be automatically used instead. The point of `super()` is to call on the parent's method when you specialize it in the child class, ie:

```
class Parent():
   def __init__(self, foo):
       self.foo = foo


class Child(Parent):
   def __init__(self, foo):
       super().__init__(foo)
       # doing something more...
       self.bar = 42
```