# Are there any guidelines available for beginning Python with Python 2.6 to write applications easily migratable to Python 3 in future?

Tags: python, python-3.x

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tips on upgrading to python 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072028/tips-on-upgrading-to-python-3-0)

I am beginning Python and Python 3 is hardly a choice today. But I want the new code I write to have no problems running or being converted to Python 3. Are there any issues known that I should keep in mind for this?

Comment: Always run with the "-3" flag, and python2.6 should inform you of any issues that "2to3" won't be able to automatically translate.

Comment: Also, this is a duplicate of many other questions. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/282819/is-it-worth-learning-python-2-6-with-3-0-coming, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072028/tips-on-upgrading-to-python-3-0

Answer (score 1):

The full correct answer is in the comments, of course - but if you only do one thing to prepare for Python 3, make it learning to use parentheses with 'print'.

Python 2.x:

```
print 'Hello, World!'
```

Python 3.x:

```
print('Hello, World!')
```

It's the number one most common error in my code when I try to write Python 3.

(And since both methods work with 2.x, you might as well go ahead and get used to using the parens!)

Comment: If you want to use print as a function (with parentheses) rather than as a statement (without parentheses) in Python 2.6 or earlier, you'll need to add this at the beginning of each module/file: `from __future__ import print_function`

Comment: Actually, I believe it works fine as long as you are printing single values.  It is only when printing multiple (comma-separated) values that the meaning of parentheses changes between Python 2 and 3.  See http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3105/#backwards-compatibility for full details.